# Multiple has many to the same Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, model-associations

I have a model Event with a nested model Attendee. Each attendee can be 1 of 3 roles (:guide, :marshal and :organizer).

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :attendees, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :guides, -> { Attendee.guide }
  has_many :marshals, -> { Attendee.marshal }
  has_many :organizers, -> { Attendee.organizer }
end
```

_

```
class Attendee < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :event

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :role, presence: true
  validates :email, email: true

  enum role: %i[guide marshal organizer]

  scope :guide, -> { where(role: :guide) }
  scope :marshal, -> { where(role: :marshal) }
  scope :organizer, -> { where(role: :organizer) }
end
```

I would like my event registration form to have nested forms for each of the role types. I am trying something like this.

```
<%= form_for @event, url: event_create_path(@event.handle) do |f| %>

    <%= f.fields_for :organizers do |f| %>
        <%= render partial: "attendee_fields", locals: {f: f} %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.fields_for :guides do |f| %>
        <%= render partial: "attendee_fields", locals: {f: f} %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.fields_for :marshals do |f| %>
        <%= render partial: "attendee_fields", locals: {f: f} %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

When a submit I receive the following error.

`uninitialized constant Event::Guide`

Any ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: Shouldn't this: `has_many :guides, -> { Attendee.guide }` be something more like: `scope :guides, -> {attendees.guide}`? (Also, I'd change that Attendee `:guide` scope to the plural form `:guides`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Event model needs to look more like this:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attendees, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :guides, -> { guide }, class_name: "Attendee"
  has_many :marshals, -> { marshal }, class_name: "Attendee"
  has_many :organizers, -> { organizer }, class_name: "Attendee"
end
```

The extra associations need to know which model they're linking with -- as the error shows, they're currently guessing that e.g. `guides` is associated with some model named `Guide`.

(You also shouldn't need those `scope`s in Attendee, I don't think... I believe `enum` defines identical ones for you automatically.)

Comment: Beauty! Thanks so much. The only other thing I was missing was the inverse relationship on it to allow it to connect the walk. `has_many :guides, -> { guide }, class_name: "Attendee", inverse_of: :walk`

Answer (score 0):

I would still go a completely different path to create a better domain model:

```
class Attendee
  has_many :attendences
  has_many :events, through: :attendences
end

class Attendance
  enum role: %i[guide marshal organizer]
  belongs_to :attendee
  belongs_to :event
end

class Event
  has_many :attendences
  has_many :attendees, through: :attendences

  Attendance.roles.each do |key,int|
    has_many key, through: :attendences,
                  source: :attendee,
                  -> { where(Attendance.call(key)) }
  end
end
```

The way you have modeled it an attendee is locked to a single role. This instead creates the roles scoped to an event.

Comment: I do agree that this would probably be the better way for an Event like model. I used Event in my example as it is easy to understand. However my actual use case is slightly different where the Attendee wouldn't be a part of anything else but the parent.